# Laravel always return date column with carbon

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to always make the dates from a column return using carbon?

Let say I have a `Challenges` model/table with `date_end` column.

When I do this call in my `ChallengesController` it returns all the `challenges` in json for my app:

```
public function index()
    {
      return response()->json([
        'status'=>'success',
        'challenges' => Auth::user()->challenges,
      ]);
    }
```

But the date is still MySQL format. I know I can do :

```
public function index()
{
      $challenges = Auth::user()->challenges;

      foreach ( $challenges as $challenge){
         $challenge['humandate'] = $challenge->date_end->diffForHumans();
       }

      return response()->json([
            'status'=>'success',
            'challenges' => $challenges,
      ]);
}
```

then get the date via `challenge.humandate` But is there a cleaner way?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Castis points out, you can use attribute mutators and accessors to modify the data is it goes to the model and as it comes from the model. In your case define getCreatedAtAttribute method, for example, and return from it Carbon and the created_at field parsed into it.

Comment: I just used `public function getDateEndAttribute($value){
    $end = new Carbon($value);
    return $end->diffForHumans();
  }`

Answer (score 9):

In your model you can declare which columns should be converted to `Carbon` instances by adding them to the `protected $dates` array:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date_end'];
```

Of course the first two are only necessary if you're using the `->timestamps()` method in your migrations.

Comment: I currently have :   `protected $dates = ['date_start','date_end',];` in my `challenge.php` model and it returns the same date, not carbon